# A strange kick from the penalty mark scored: should a goal be given?

Tags: rules, football, officiating, tie-breaker, penalty-shot

During October 2017, a football game in Thailand went to twenty (20) rounds of sudden death in kicks from the penalty mark.

The twentieth kick for the team going first hit the crossbar and deflected high into the air. As the goalkeeper celebrated the miss, the ball landed and bounced. The spin it picked up from the deflection caused movement towards the goal.

It crossed the line before the goalkeeper could realise and reach it. The officials awarded a goal (shown by signal in video). The opposing team missed their next shot and lost the match because of the strange penalty being scored. The BBC have a video of this incident [here](http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/41728826).

Was the referee correct in law and in best practice to award such a goal? Does the losing team have any right to appeal the result due to the "error in law"?

Comment: I've added a link to the BBC footage of this incident; I'm not sure if its country-locked or not - if it is and there's some *legal* footage of this elsewhere, please link to that instead.

Comment: Not a duplicate. This question requires further information on whether such a decision can be appealed, on basis of whether the decision is valid in law.

Comment: Teams can appeal anything they like - they may just get short shrift from the governing body. And as the potential duplicate makes clear, there wasn't an error in the law here.